# ListView image random

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a listview with item. When I scroll, images appear randomly. 
I don't know why...
There's the adapter :

```
package com.forel.dbc;
[...]

public class AgendaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Data> items; //Le contenu
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;     
private SmartImageView myImage;

public AgendaAdapter(Context context, List<Data> items, DownloaderImageViewCache imageCache, boolean invertTextColor) {

    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.imageCache = imageCache; 
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

[...]
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_list_item, parent, false);

    }
    final Data event = (Data) getItem(position);
    if (event.getTitle() != null)
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventName)).setText(event.getTitle());
    if (event.getDesc() != null)
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(event.getDesc());

    ((SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_image)).setImageUrl(event.getPicture()); // getPicture return imageUrl, 

    return convertView;
}}
```

The images appear randomly in the list

If someone has an idea ...

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the SmartImageView library.

Answer (score 2):

Am I correct in assuming that these images are being loaded over a network connection? If so that would explain your problem, as you're setting the image, which in turn starts a background progress to fetch the images.

Chances are you're moving around the list, cause refreshes and as such the images are being loaded in to the incorrect ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the image after download you should make sure that the data associated with this view has not changed meanwhile.